# cakephp paginate post data

Tags: php, cakephp

i need to create search method with pos data :

search method :

```
public function find_estate () {

        if(isset($this->request->data['type'])){
            $type =$this->request->data['type'] ;           
        }else{$type="";}
           if($type!=""){
               if ($type != "all"){
               $where[] = "Estate.melk_type LIKE '$type'";
               }
           }
           }

if(isset($where)){         

         $this->paginate = 
             array(
                     'Estate'=>
                        array(

                            'limit' => 4,
                            'order' => array(
                                'Estate.eid' => 'desc'
                            ),

                             'fields' => array('eid','melk_type','status ','image'),
                             'conditions' => implode(" AND ",$where), 

                            ));     

                 $this->set('estate',$this->paginate()); 

   }    
}
```

but not working in other page of search result 
How do I paging with post data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send $type param when you're switching pages, also I would use get method if it's a simple search with one field, from what I see you don't test for the method so you could easily add search param to the URLs in pagination

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927209/cakephp-paginate-with-post-data-without-sessions-serialization-or-post-to-get)'s another question about this, you can also try official [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html)

Comment: This is the code for a sample of 5 parameters ​​can be used to search .

how do i send param with paginate ? please with code sample